# How angular *ngFor detect changes on mutable items

Tags: angular

I'm trying to understand how [*ngFor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts) works internally by using `IterableDiffers` to detect changes in a collection.

The default implementation of `IterableDiffers` is [DefaultIterableDiffer](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/08ea38f1972aeb2433323d941bfadba65c95d751/packages/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_iterable_differ.ts#L149) and to compare two values (from the old and the new collection) it uses `===` operator. Relying to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/db4f5087372b0db1b8f736b5ab4beb350f506a99/packages/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_iterable_differ.ts#L179) method:

```js
export function looseIdentical(a: any, b: any): boolean {
  return a === b || typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number' && isNaN(a) && isNaN(b);
}
```

**So logically, if the collection contains objects and the references of these objects ares not changed there will be no detect change.**

**BUT**, this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-detect-change) shows the opposite :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = [
    {id: 1, name: 'youyi'},
    {id: 2, name: 'kouki'},
    {id: 3, name: 'kouka'}
  ];

  constructor() {
     interval(1000).subscribe((i) => this.items[1].name = "kouki-" + i);
  }
}
```

After each second passed I can see the value of the second object incrementing without changing its reference !

What I am messing ? which part of code do this comparison ?

Comment: Suppose you have no ngFor at all, and you just have {{ item.name }} in your template. Angular detects the change if you change the name of the item. The same happens for every expression used inside an ngFor. The differ is used to test which elements are inserted and removed, but it doesn't care about expressions used inside the ngFor.

Comment: Agree with @JBNizet, it has nothing to do with ngFor. Angular just checks your template and since you've mutated property then it will be reflected on the screen. I also remember one article https://vsavkin.com/change-detection-in-angular-2-4f216b855d4c where author said `Angular has to be conservative and run all the checks every single time because the JavaScript language does not give us object mutation guarantees.`

Comment: Have a look on this :https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/

Comment: thanks for you guys, its more clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngFor` tracks array of objects by reference. So, if new reference of array of objects is passed to the `ngFor`, even the array has the same values, Angular will remove an old array and a new collection with the same values will be redrawn.

However, you can use `trackBy` of `ngFor` to set what property should be a trigger to update DOM.

Now we know that `ngFor` will be redrawn if new reference is assigned to the variable of `ngFor`. Nevertheless, values are changed in `ngFor` even reference is the same. Why?

Because there is NgZone. NgZone notifies that something changed and Angular updates DOM. NgZones has `onTurnDone` event. Whenever this event is fired, it executes a tick() function which essentially performs change detection.

[You can read more here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

**UPDATE:**

[As Angular docs says about ngFor and identifying whether the data is changed:](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description)

> The identities of elements in the iterator can change while the data
>   does not. This can happen, for example, if the iterator is produced
>   from an RPC to the server, and that RPC is re-run. Even if the data
>   hasn't changed, the second response produces objects with different
>   identities, and Angular must tear down the entire DOM and rebuild it
>   (as if all old elements were deleted and all new elements inserted).

Comment: I do not agree with you in this part: `Angular will remove an old array and a new collection with the same values will be redrawn.` Angular tracks only changes in the collection by reference and if the array reference change we can rely on trackBy to enhance comparaison. Yo can use the same array and add/remove elements from it by calling `push/pop/splice` then you will not see other elements redrawn. Beside, I accept the rest of your answer

Comment: Yep, as I said Angular do nothing to the array, the RPC send new array while data is the same (this is where trackBy is interesting). This not an action done by Angular, thus the sentence above is not correct for me.

Comment: @bubbles docs says ` Angular must tear down the entire DOM and rebuild it (as if all old elements were deleted and all new elements inserted).`

Comment: When ? from the docs `the second response produces objects with different identities`. In other words, the reference of the array has changed. And I'm ok with this. But, when the reference of the array is not changed, angular will not tear down the entire DOM. Do you agree with me ?

Comment: @bubbles yeah, I agree. Then the `NgZone` comes and Angular will update just necessary DOM element.

Comment: I just saw the if in your answer :) `So, if new reference of array of objects`. Sorry

Comment: @bubbles glad to help you!:)